# How to embed Tkinter internally with C++?

Tags: python, c++, tkinter

I'm writing a C++ .dll project, which is injected into another process, and I'm trying to implement embedded Python code. As far as I have described it, this is working. For instance when I inject the .dll, I run the following code:

```
Py_Initialize();
FILE* PScriptFile = std::fopen("D:\\test.py", "r");
if (PScriptFile) PyRun_SimpleFile(PScriptFile, "D:\\test.py");
```

`test.py` is a simple script which opens and writes to a text file. Thus, I know that my .dll is running the script because I can see that this text file is created in the directory of the main executable. Now, I want to run the following script:

```
import tkinter as tk
window = tk.Tk()
window.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW",window.destroy)
window.mainloop()
```

I know that this script works on its own. However, when I try to embed it, no Tkinter window pops up.

Thanks

Comment: Tkinter is itself a wrapper around an embedded tcl interpreter, meaning you would have a your project calling python calling tcl. Is that really what you want? It might be easier to directly embed tcl/tk if your primary goal is a tk-based UI.

Comment: I don't really need a specific UI. In fact, the running a python script seems to be the most "general" solution, so that I can use it as a base for other projects where the application changes. That is, I want my UI framework to be mostly independent of the application and my DLL. That is why embedding seems nice. I can think of an immediate work around, but it doesn't feel as satisfying.

Comment: Does your C++ project already have a GUI?  You can't start another main loop if there's already one running.  You could do so in a separate thread, if you had to.

Comment: My point was, you can embed python which embeds tcl, or you can directly embed tcl and avoid the python middleman.

Comment: @BryanOakley My embedded python is just meant to launch another script. That way, the python code is independent of the C++

Comment: Tcl can do that for you as well, and was designed from the ground up to be embeddable. Ultimately it's your call, but it seems like having a product that embeds one other language is going to be less complex than one that has to embed two.